# MPMoviePlayerControll doesn't detect touch when in fullscreen mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have subclassed MPMoviePlayerController...

```
@interface CustomMoviePlayerController : UIViewController 
{   
    NSURL *movieUrlPath;
    MPMoviePlayerController *mp;    
...
```

I also have iPad application (with splitView). On the right side in the center I load this player and start playing movie...

```
cPlayer = [[CustomMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithUrlPath:title];          
    [self.view addSubview:cPlayer.view];        
    [cPlayer readyPlayer:title];
```

I have touchBegin/End methods that detect touch on this player and it works, but when I set player in fullscreen it stop detect toucher. Why touches stop detecting in fullscreen?

```
[cPlayer.mp setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the player enters fullscreen mode, it's no longer attached to the view, but to a new window.

You could listen to `MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification` and `MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification` to do stuff when the player enters fullscreen mode. You could get the player window with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]` and add an overlay view with gestures recognizers.

Comment: Thnaks this saved the day :) ... [cPlayer.mp setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
 
 UIView *v = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
 [v addSubview:myOverlayChannelPicker];